# Show that $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = y\vec{i}-x\vec{j}$ is not a gradient field.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

By definition, for this to be a gradient field, it must satisfy the condition that for a function $\phi$ : $\Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}$, $F_1(x,y,z) = \frac{d\phi}{dx}$ $F_2(x,y,z) = \frac{d\phi}{dy}$ and $F_3(x,y,z) = \frac{d\phi}{dz}$

Or equivalently $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=\operatorname{grad}(\phi)(x,y,z) = \frac{d\phi}{dx}(x,y,z)\vec{\mathrm{i}}+\frac{d\phi}{dy}(x,y,z)\vec{\mathrm{j}}+\frac{d\phi}{dz}(x,y,z)\vec{\mathrm{k}}$

For my function, $\vec{F}(x,y,z)$ = $y\vec{\mathrm{i}}-x\vec{\mathrm{j}} +0\vec{\mathrm{k}}$, these conditions are satisfied, since $\frac{d\phi}{dx}(x,y,z) = y$ and $\frac{d\phi}{dy}(x,y,z) = -x$ and $\frac{d\phi}{dz} =0$

So therefore it is a gradient field. But I'm supposed to show that it is not a gradient field. How can I do so, if the conditions for it being a gradient field are satisfied?

Comment: Is it $\phi_{xy}=\phi_{yx}?$

Comment: What do you mean? Where?

Comment: I mean that $\phi_x=y, \phi_y=-x$ and $\phi_{xy}=1\ne -1=\phi_{yx}.$

Comment: Does the condition for it being a gradient field require that $\phi_xy = \phi_yx$ ?

Comment: It is because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: This is not a requirment for a gradient field by definition of a gradient field.

Comment: It is $\nabla \phi=(\phi_x,\phi_y,\phi_z).$ So one has that $\phi_{xy}=\phi_{yx},\phi_{xz}=\phi_{zx}$ and $\phi_{yz}=\phi_{zy}.$ It is not a requirement, it is a consequence of the way $\nabla \phi$ is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curl of a gradient field vanishes.

If

$\vec F = y \vec i - x \vec j \tag 1$

were a gradient field, then we would have

$\nabla \times \vec F = 0; \tag 2$

but

$\nabla \times \vec F$
$= (\vec F_{z,y} - \vec F_{y, z})\vec i +  (\vec F_{x, z} - \vec F_{z, x})\vec j +  (\vec F_{y, x} - \vec F_{x, y})\vec k = -2\vec k \ne 0; \tag 3$

thus $\vec F$ is not a gradient vector field.

Answer (score 1):

From $\phi_x = y$ we get that $\phi(x,y) = xy+C(y)$ for some function $C$ so
$$-x = \phi_y = x+C'(y)$$
which is a contradiction. Hence there is no such $\phi$.